# Poly line is not appearing between two locations in google maps xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

Marker between 2 locations are displayed but polyline is not getting displayed and getting response as

```
 "{error_message :This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. 
Request received from IP address , with empty referrer,
   "routes" : [],"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,I solved the issue by restricting  direction ApI key as None.

Answer (score 0):

It says something about your API key. Have you entered and given your API key in the correct way?

Comment: Thanks the issue was with key restriction type

Comment: You welcome ;) Don't forget to mark your question as answered.